# how do I generate one fasta file only with the reference and the virus name that are in the header of a file multifasta in perl

Tags: perl, task, fasta

I need your help.

I did a perl script that converts multifasta files to fasta file.
For Example:

In multi-fasta file contains:

> gi|983431797|ref|NZ_LN000000.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 1
>   CTGACTGGGAGTACGAAGGCCGCCTGCACAAGACAACGGGGCAGCGAACCTTCTTCTGCACCGGCACGGA
>
> gi|983431797|ref|NZ_LN123456.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 2
>   CTGACTGGGAGTACGAAGGCCGCCTGCACAAGACAACGGGGCAGCGAACCTTCTTCTGCACCGGCACGGA
>
> gi|983431797|ref|NZ_LN457532.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 3

CTGACTGGGAGTACGAAGGCCGCCTGCACAAGACAACGGGGCAGCGAACCTTCTTCTGCACCGGCACGGA

My script does this:

file1.fa

> gi|983431797|ref|NZ_LN000000.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 1
>   CTGACTGGGAGTACGAAGGCCGCCTGCACAAGACAACGGGGCAGCGAACCTTCTTCTGCACCGGCACGGA

file2.fa

> gi|983431797|ref|NZ_LN123456.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 2
>   CTGACTGGGAGTACGAAGGCCGCCTGCACAAGACAACGGGGCAGCGAACCTTCTTCTGCACCGGCACGGA

in different fasta files.

But I need my script to generate a file containing all the references that are in multifasta file.
For example:

fileReferences.txt: 
ref|NZ_LN000000.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 1
ref|NZ_LN123456.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 2
ref|NZ_LN457532.1| Nocardia farcinica genome assembly NCTC11134, chromosome : 3

Do you understand?

I'm sorry, I'm new in perl language, I did the first script after much research, but I can't finish it. So if anyone can help me, I will be grateful.
P.S: Forgive my English. ^^

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

use warnings;

use IO::File;

my $usage = "\nUSAGE: perl $0 <Fasta>"."\n";

print $usage and exit unless($ARGV[0]);

my $input  = IO::File->new("$ARGV[0]");

my $output = "";


while(my $line = $input->getline)

{

    chomp($line);

    if($line =~ /^>/)

    {

         if($output ne "")

         {

              close ($output);

         }

         $line =~ s/^>//;

         $output  = IO::File->new("> $line.fa");

         print $output ">".$line."\n";

      }

      else

      {

          print $output $line."\n";

      }

  }


close ($input);

close ($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want first line of every `*.fa` file in a `fileReferences.txt`? If so, try this:

```
awk 'FNR==1' *.fa > fileReferences.txt
```

Comment: But I need to do this in the script itself